# Running Dacpac in SQL Server 2019 - Error SQL72018: SqlTable could not be imported but one or more of these objects exist in your source

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 database which I'm running a dacpac against using `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll`. I'm using Powershell (tried on v5.1 and v6.x). When I pointed the same Powershell script to SQL Server 2019 the following error was raised:

```
Exception calling "GenerateDeployReport" with "4" argument(s): "An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue
   Error SQL72018: SqlTable could not be imported but one or more of these objects exist in your source.
```

I tried

- Running against a remote and local SQL Server 2019 instance which didn't work when using the same database.
- Creating a new dacpac project targeting the same SQL 2019 database with one table and it didn't work.
- It worked on an empty database
- It worked on the target database after I deleted all the tables, sprocs, views, functions, etc. were still in there.

I was using a Docker image I built to do this and I thought I was using the latest dac version as I rebuilt the docker image to pull the latest sqlpackage from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded to the latest version of sqlpackage which includes `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll` and it now works. It went from

```
# sqlpackage-linux-x64-150.4057.1.zip
RUN curl -Lq https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=873926 -o sqlpackage-linux-x64-latest.zip
```

to

```
# Version 18.6, Build 15.0.4897.1
RUN curl -Lq https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2143497 -o sqlpackage-linux-x64-latest.zip
```

I thought my Docker build was getting the latest sqlpackage but it wasn't.

Its a shame the exception isn't more descriptive from Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks, I had the exact same problem with the same version.  The new version does fix it, even though there's no explicit mention in the [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/release-notes-sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver15#fixes)